# What cause the Firebug message "Debugger scope is not live"?

Tags: firebug

I'm running Firefox 24.0 and Firebug 1.8.4.

I am new to Firebug; I usually use Chrome for development, so this might be something obvious once I've used Firebug more.

I am stepping through code and every line of Javascript that is executed results in the message "Debugger scope is not live" in the console.

I also cannot see any HTML in the HTML tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded Firebug to 1.12.4 - both problems are gone. The question is, at best, of academic interest at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.8.4 of Firebug is not compatible to Firefox 24.0. You should actually have got 1.12.4 via the automatic updates.

If you have automatic add-on updates enabled and you got the old Firebug version, it may be related to [Mozilla bug 823840](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=823840). In that case you may want to leave a comment there that it's not fixed yet.

Sebastian